# Can't boot with mSATA

Tags: boot, sata

I used to run Ubuntu with a 16 GB mSATA SSD (referred to as mSATA from now on) holding my root directory and a 1 TB HDD holding /home. I like to install everything I see, and thus I ran out of room. I recently installed a 250 GB SSD in place of my HDD and still want to be able to use my mSATA SSD.

However, when I attempt to boot with the mSATA in, the laptop automatically boots from the mSATA, even if I change the firmware boot device priority. When I attempt to boot from the mSATA I get stuck at "loading ramdisk". When I remove the mSATA, my laptop boots fine, but then I can't access my mSATA when I plug it in while running. When I attempt to use a USB with Ubuntu it gives me a kernel panic.

I don't have an mSATA to USB converter.
How can I go about deleting the files on my mSATA and booting from my new SSD?

Other notes: I only use Ubuntu (no dual boot to worry about). I have four partitions on my new SSD: /boot/efi, /, /home, and swap (future home of Arch, Mint, or some other distribution).